# Style DataGridRow WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Tengo un `DataGrid` con un `DataGridTemplateColumn`, un otras columnas que se cargan de forma dinamica, estoy intentando cambiar el `background` cuando la propiedad `Eliminado` esta en `true`, pero no me ha funcionado de ninguna forma.

El `DataGrid` esta de la siguiente manera.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Name="gridDataUserControl" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}" Style="{DynamicResource estilodatagrid}" EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
                  CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" Padding="0,0,3,0" IsReadOnly="True" CellStyle="{DynamicResource estilodatagridcell}" RowStyle="{StaticResource estilodatagridrow}"
                  extension:DataGridColumnExtension.Columns="{Binding Columnas}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderCheckbox">
                    <CheckBox Name="SelectAll" IsEnabled="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=Tag, Mode=TwoWay}" Checked="DataGridCheckBoxColumnChecked" Unchecked="DataGridCheckBoxColumnChecked" />
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemCheckbox">
                    <CheckBox  VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Seleccionado, Mode=TwoWay}" Checked="DataGridCheckBoxColumnChecked" Unchecked="DataGridCheckBoxColumnChecked" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Visibility="{Binding VerColumnaCheck}" x:Name="CheckAll"  HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderCheckbox}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ItemCheckbox}">
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Y el estilo de `estilodatagridrow` es

```
<Style x:Key="estilodatagridrow" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Coral" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Eliminado}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Eliminado}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Esta tu ViewModel implementanto la interfaz `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de nada, hay algo que tienes que comprobar, y es que tu 'Model' y tu 'ViewModel', implementen INotifyPropertyChanged, que supongo que es una regla básica y lo habrás comprobado.

En segundo lugar, hay algo que me parece muy extraño en tu RowStyle, y es que aplicas el DataTrigger en dos ocasiones, la primera en el Template (algo no demasiado acertado, ya que no modificas nada de la misma) y una segunda en el propio style. Lo confuso además es que lo haces para pintar la row de colores diferentes.

La cuestión es que pienso que eliminando la parte del Template en el style debería de funcionarte.

Te muestro un ejemplo muy simple que funciona hasta en tiempo de ejecución:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Añado el código XALM para que puedas verlo más detenidamente:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="387.333" Width="696.333">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Datos}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PropiedadBool}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.